# How to name a 'group' check box in Adobe Reader when wanting to fill form by FDF / XFDF

Tags: php, pdf, adobe-reader, fdf

I've managed to populate ordinary pdf text fields via an fdf file and via an xfdf file. My problem is that I need to check some checkboxes.

I have read [this article entitled 'FDF - how to check a checkbox?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420673/fdf-how-to-check-a-checkbox) but I still can't get mine to work.

One of the things I'm confused with is how I should be naming the checkboxes on the pdf form. If I have a group of radio buttons called 'gender' how do I name them on the pdf form. Is there the same idea of a radio group for the checkboxes on an Adobe form?

So far, and using the 'gender' example, I have simply named the checkboxes 'genderM' and 'genderF', but the fdf:

```
<< /T (genderM) /V (Yes) >>
```

does not check the 'genderM' box.

Really grateful for any help on this issue and any advice on best practices.

Recap:

1. Does Adobe Reader have the concept of a checkbox or radio group when naming the input fields for the pdf form?
2. Whether yes or no, how do I check the box?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Took me quite a while to figure out where I was going wrong. The syntax shown in my question was correct as per the other article I referenced.

[image: Adobe Reader Checkbox Property Form]

I was using someone else's form and they had set the Export Value field (while editing the pdf form in Adobe Reader) for the checkbox to 'ON'. It seems like the Export Value field determines what word you use to select the checkbox. So I should have been using the fdf line:

```
<< /T (genderM) /V (ON) >>
```

The default value, as shown in the above image is 'Yes', which would mean I use:

```
<< /T (genderM) /V (Yes) >>
```

Hope that helps someone in future.

Cheers

Comment: Just to round out the answer... The unchecked value will always be "Off"