# Fdf to pdf How to check a checkbox on pdf filling

Tags: php, pdf, fdf

I am using FDF to fill the pdf with php . I have some checkboxes in the pdf .

I searched a lot on interment . I refered these links [refer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420673/fdf-how-to-check-a-checkbox) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508964/how-to-name-a-group-check-box-in-adobe-reader-when-wanting-to-fill-form-by-fdf).

currently i used this

```
<</T(form1[0].#subform[6].Checkbox1a[0])/V(1)>>
<</T(form1[0].#subform[6].Checkbox1b[0])/V(checked)>>
<</T(form1[0].#subform[6].Checkbox1c[0])/V(yes)>>
<</T(form1[0].#subform[6].Checkbox1d[0])/V(on)>>
```

I have tried 1, checked, yes , on etc but failed to ckeck the checkbox . this is one of the pdf i am using to fill [pdf link](http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf)

Comment: What is the return value of the checkbox? Are you sure that it is a PDF form? the field naming looks a lot like XFA to me. Do text fields fill properly?

Comment: yes text fields are ok . Only problem is checkbox and radio box

Comment: In this case, you have to find the return value of the box, and that is to become the /V value in your FDF. So, if it is "yes", it would be /V(yes), if it is "hullaboo", it would be /V(hullaboo). A special case is "unchecked", which is always "Off".

Answer (score 0):

In the PDF specification the V entry of a check box is described as following:

> The V entry in the field dictionary [...] holds a **name object** representing the check box’s appearance state, which shall be used to select the appropriate appearance from the appearance dictionary.

It is also defined that the name for the in state *should* be `Yes` but that's not always the case. In your document the on state is defined as `Y`.

So your FDF data should look like:

```
<</T(form1[0].#subform[6].Checkbox1a[0])/V/Y>>
```

For completion: If the export value is non-Latin text (by using an Opt array) e.g. Acrobat doesn't use a name object but a string, too:

```
<</T(form1[0].#subform[6].Checkbox1a[0])/V(Y)>>
```

This behaviour seems to be un-documentated.

Comment: it works . A question . will it be same for all the pdfs?? I mean i have to use Y for every checkbox to checked or there may be some different??

Comment: No, it depends on the export value of the checkbox, which you or your programm needs to know. Only the off state is defined as "shall be [...] the name **Off**".