# How to properly parse a PDF and read if checkboxes are checked

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, node-pdfkit, hummus.js

I'm trying to parse PDF forms on server side. I tried many node.js modules like pdf2json, hummus and node-pdftk and I'm able to get all the text fields but not if checkboxes are checked.

I've been testing with different files (like [this one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlmk9l2q927nbe4/n400.pdf?dl=0)) and pdf2json always returns an empty string as every checkbox value while hummus gives *true*. With pdftk I get FieldValue and FieldStateOption fields and compare them as I read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35977963) but neither the result seems to be correct.

Can anybody give me some advice, please?

Answer (score 0):

See if using the [pdffiller](https://github.com/pdffillerjs/pdffiller) package works. The `generateFDFTemplate` method should do the trick. As per the README:

```
var pdfFiller = require('pdffiller');

var sourcePDF = "test/test.pdf";

// Override the default field name regex. Default: /FieldName: ([^\n]*)/
var nameRegex = null;  

var FDF_data = pdfFiller.generateFDFTemplate( sourcePDF, nameRegex, function(err, fdfData) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(fdfData);
});
```

will print out:

```
{
    "last_name" : "",
    "first_name" : "",
    "date" : "",
    "football" : "",
    "baseball" : "",
    "basketball" : "",
    "hockey" : "",
    "nascar" : ""
};
```

Hope this helps :)